# Sphinx using Python3 interpreter instead of Python2

Tags: pycharm, python-sphinx

I installed Sphinx lately for python 2.x based on the instructions: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html.

After I generate all the .rst files, I did a "make html" to generate the html file. However, when it builds the files, it does not use the Pycharm project interpreter which is python 2.7, instead it uses python 3.6:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219:

Because of that, it introduce a bunch of "No Module Names xx" issue. The python path is set to the project so i am pretty sure the issue is not because of that. Any one can give me some clue about how I can force it to build by using Python 2.7 on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix would be to create a new virtual environment of python 2.7.  Then, do `pip install sphinx`. I would suggest using `sphinx_apidoc.exe` and `sphinx_build.exe` instead of `make html`. Those exes can be run with various options which is really helpful.